# How can I remove the buggy ubuntu software center that replaced snap store, Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-center

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 since it's release, I've managed to remove the trashy Ubuntu software center. But after some updates it has returned, and this time it doesn't want to be purged I've tried to remove it by using these commands:

```
sudo apt remove --purge ubuntu-software
sudo apt remove --purge gnome-software
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

Nothing is working... Pls, help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image] The Software app package is named *gnome-software* in Ubuntu 20.04. To remove it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove --purge gnome-software
sudo apt-mark hold gnome-software
```

The `hold` option of `apt-mark` is used to mark a package as held back, which will block the package from being installed, upgraded or removed.

The Software app in 20.04 does have a few bugs in it. It can use ~300MB RAM when it is open which is not so bad if your computer has more than enough RAM. The other bug is that the Software app shows a notification  to update a package a package that isn't even installed. If you click the Update button to update it, the Software app shows another notification that it can't update the package because it's not installed. I tried to understand why the Software app would show a notification like that. I upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 and maybe that package was uninstalled by the upgrade. Purge + uninstall may get rid of some of the Software app's cached data too.

Comment: It's not working. It says: Package 'gnome-software' is not installed, so not removed.

Comment: So if `gnome-software` is not installed, then the application you are talking about is probably the Snap Store. There is some mixup as it is called Snap Store in the application menu (at least in GNOME Flashback DE), but if you select the "About" menu option in this application it says "Ubuntu Software" (while the GNOME Software application says just "Software").
If you don't like it, then maybe try to actually **install** GNOME Software instead of trying to remove it :) (both can work side-by-side; I have them both, for example). There's no other replacement, I think.

Comment: sudo snap remove snap-store worked earlier (long time ago), but now doesn't do nothing. The Ubuntu software or gnome center returns strangely after I reinstall snap store. I don't know what's going on... I only want to use snap store.

Comment: I don't understand - do you want or do you not want to use Snap Store? Because Snap Store and Ubuntu Software are **the same thing** in 20.04. Ubuntu Software is just another name for Snap Store (or the other way). So if you want to use Snap Store (== Ubuntu Software) you cannot uninstall it. If you uninstall it, you cannot use it. That's obvious. GNOME Software is a different application, however, although both look very similar.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working...  Ubuntu or gnome software replaced snap store...

Comment: @raj, I only want to use snap store and not Ubuntu or gnome software or whatever it's called because it's very buggy. Sometimes it's very slow, sometimes apps aren't reachable (Canonical version) or sometimes the homepage is blank and among others things...

Comment: There is no other "Snap Store" besides the one that is also called "Ubuntu Software". There is also another, similar (but different) app called "GNOME Software". The most important difference is that Snap Store installs only snaps while GNOME software can install also .deb packages. Maybe that picture will explain it better: http://rafa.eu.org/share/public/ubuntu_software.png

Comment: Well, I will to stick on Ubuntu software I guess... Anyway thanks for support

Comment: I had 2 software centers, but one of them had less apps and was more glitchy and didn't follow any gtk themes. I did `sudo snap remove snap-store` and kept `gnome-software` and it's fine. There must've been 3 desktop files for the same snap store, because there were three different "apps" in my applications overview that led to the same exact store. But since I removed `snap-store` everything's fine.

Comment: I prefer gnome-software too.